# jQuery, PHP include

Tags: php, jquery, content-management-system, include

There is this (if I may say so), horrible CMS called Vivvo. It will not, for whatever reason, allow php includes (pretty sure allow_url_fopen is disabled).

I decided to use jQuery. Here is a simple test I wrote for the php include. It seems simple- select div, insert php. Won't work locally, or remotely, anywhere. Code is certainly messed up. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Blah</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#sc_feed").load('parse.php');    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sc_feed">  THIS IS THE FEED</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will only work if the only thing the include file is used for is to output web content. It doesn't help if it defines PHP functions to call in the main PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Vivvo CMS** you can't add **jQuery** easily, so you should add small line after it and it will be like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict()</script>
```

then you should replace any '**$**' sign in you jQuery code with '**jQuery**' so your code will

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery("#sc_feed").load('parse.php');    
</script>
```

because **VIVVO CMS** uses **Prototype Javascript library** , and it couldn't be used with **jquery** togther without any edit

Hope this will help you ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your jquery function in a document ready function. Plus your selector should start with a # for ids

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sc_feed").load('parse.php');
 });
```

Comment: His selector does start with `#`.

Comment: I'm sure he's trying in inject the output from a php file into the document.

Comment: I'm injecting a parsed feed into the page, using jQuery. It is "web content" in the general sense. The parser is written in PHP. PHP includes won't work on the stupid CMS I have to build this into.